# Algebra and sigma-algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory

could someone clarify the following, please?
About the difference between an algebra and a sigma-algebra, is it correct that if $\Omega$ is finite and any possible operation on it is finite, then it is also a sigma-algebra, while if countable operations are possible but are not in the algebra, then it is just an algebra?
Moreover, if $\Omega$ is infinite, like the set of Reals or positive integers, is it still possible to construct an algebra on it? I mean, if $\Omega$ is infinite, then any finite subset in it would have an infinite complement (for example as a countable union of sets); therefore, I would say that if $\Omega$ is infinite, it can't be an algebra but only a sigma-algebra, is that correct?
I hope to have been clear!

Comment: See also wikipedia for [Algebra over a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field), e.g., the algebra of complex numbers.

Comment: I did search already and I didn't find an answer to my question..

Comment: So the answer with this definition is, that an infinite $\Omega$ like the real numbers has an algebra structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a finite set $\Omega$ any algebra (of sets) is automatically a $\sigma$-algebra of sets, yes, as infinite operations like countable unions always reduce to finite ones.

On an infinite subset, say $\Omega= \Bbb N$ we can both have algebras that are not $\sigma$-algebras and "proper" $\sigma$-algebras.

In the latter category we have the powerset $\mathscr{P}(\Omega)$, e.g. and in the former we have the algebra of all subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ that are finite or such that $\Omega \setminus A$ is finite. This is clearly not a $\sigma$-algebra, and the examples work for any infinite set $\Omega$.